# Which compiler is used to make .cod files?

Tags: compiler-construction, blackberry

Which compiler is used in Blackberry development to make .cod files? Is it rapc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `rapc` converts J2ME jar files into cod files, which are proprietary to BlackBerry devices. Example:

```
rapc import="c:\program files\research in motion\blackberry JDE 3.7\lib\net_rim_api.jar" codename=$your_app -midlet jad=$your_app.jad $your_app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry Ant Tools 
http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/

The above wraps up all the rapc/alx commands so that you can use from your normal IDE rather than having to resort to the Blackberry JDEs which will quickly cause you to loose the will to live